# Iterating through tables with map function and function that queries other dataframes

Tags: loops, pyspark, bigdata

I have two tables: Table A

```
|Group ID  | User ids in group|
| -------- | -------------- |
| 11       | [45,46,47,48]  |
| 20       | [49,10,11,12]  |
| 31       | [55,7,48,43]   |
```

and Table B:

```
| User ids| Related Id     |
| ------- | -------------- |
| 1       | [5,6,7,8]      |
| 2       | [6, 9, 10,11]  |
| 3       | [1, 2, 5, 7]   |
```

And I have a reference table that has the info: Reference table:

```
| User ids | Group ID |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 11             |
| 2        | 20             |
| 3        | 31             |
```

This is just a minimal sample, I have this situation with millions of rows on each table. I am trying to use pyspark (or sql but I haven't figured out a way to do it here) to iterate through *User ids* column in the reference table and get the intersection between the lists of *User ids in group* from Table A and *Related Id* from Table B.

So in the end, I would like to have a table of the form:

```
| User ids | Intersection   |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 2        | [10, 11]       |
| 3        | [7]            |
```

In Pyspark Id have a function of the form:

```
def test_function(user_id, ref_df, tableB_df, tableA_df):
    group_id = int(ref_df.filter(ref_df.userID == user_id).collect()[0][1])
    group_list = tableA_df.filter(tableA_df.groupID == group_id)
    related_id_list = tableB_df.filter(tableB_df.userID == user_id)
    
    return group_list.intsersection(related_id_list)


abc = ref_df.rdd.map(lambda x: test_function(x, ref_df, tableB_df, tableA_df))
```

However, when I run this function I am getting the following error:

> An error was encountered:
> Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Can anyone give any suggestion on how to solve this problem? Or how to modify my approach to solve this problem? Since my table has millions of rows, I want to use pyspark as best as possible to make use of the parallelization abilities as much as possible. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You first `join` the reference table with table a on `Group ID`, and join the resulting table with table b on `User ids`. This will give you a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+-----------------+--------------+
|User ids|Group ID|User ids in group|    Related Id|
+--------+--------+-----------------+--------------+
|       1|      11| [45, 46, 47, 48]|  [5, 6, 7, 8]|
|       2|      20| [49, 10, 11, 12]|[6, 9, 10, 11]|
|       3|      31|  [55, 7, 48, 43]|  [1, 2, 5, 7]|
+--------+--------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Then you perform an intersection on column `User ids in group` and `Related Id`. This gives you the columns you want, but you need to filter rows where the intersection is empty.

The code snippet below does all of that in pyspark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
# Init example tables
table_a = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(11, [45, 46, 47, 48]), (20, [49, 10, 11, 12]), (31, [55, 7, 48, 43])],
    ["Group ID", "User ids in group"],
)
table_b = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, [5, 6, 7, 8]), (2, [6, 9, 10, 11]), (3, [1, 2, 5, 7])],
    ["User ids", "Related Id"],
)
reference_table = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 11), (2, 20), (3, 31)], ["User ids", "Group ID"]
)
# Relevant code
joined_df = reference_table.join(table_a, on="Group ID").join(table_b, on="User ids")
intersected_df = joined_df.withColumn("Intersection", F.array_intersect("User ids in group", "Related Id"))
intersected_df.select("User ids", "Intersection").filter(F.size("Intersection") > 0).show()
```

output:

```
+--------+------------+
|User ids|Intersection|
+--------+------------+
|       2|    [10, 11]|
|       3|         [7]|
+--------+------------+
```